# Verifying password_hash() in PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use the bcrypt algorithm for hashing the passwords but I've ran into a couple of problems. First of all, I can't find the appropriate spot to check whether `password_verify()` returns true.

```
$admin = $_POST['admin-user'];
$pass = $_POST['admin-pass'];

$password_hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (isset($admin)&&isset($pass)&&!empty($admin)&&!empty($pass)) {

$admin_select = $link->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = :admin");

$admin_passwd = $link->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = :admin_pw");
$admin_passwd->execute(array(':admin_pw' => $admin));
$admin_pwd = $admin_passwd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (password_verify($pass, $admin_pwd)){

            if ($admin_select->execute(array(':admin' => $admin))) {
                $res = $link->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests');
                $query_num_rowz = $res->fetchColumn();
            if ($query_num_rowz == 0) {
                echo 'No records found';
            } else if ($query_num_rowz > 0) {
                $query = $link->prepare("SELECT id FROM admins WHERE username = :admin");
                 $query->execute(array(':admin' => $admin));
                 $admin_id = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $admin_id;
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second of all, I'm not sure this is the right way to select the user's password.

```
$admin_passwd = $link->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = :admin_pw");
$admin_passwd->execute(array(':admin_pw' => $admin));
$admin_pwd = $admin_passwd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't put `->fetch` in a loop, the single invocation will return a single row of associative array. You must access the proper index first (in this case `password`). Then compare the row value (at least if this is hashed already) inside the `password_verify` with the user input. Rough example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['admin-user'] && !empty($_POST['admin-pass']))) {
    $admin = $_POST['admin-user'];
    $pass = $_POST['admin-pass'];

    $admin_info = $link->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = :admin_user");
    $admin_info->execute(array(':admin_user' => $admin));
    $row = $admin_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row && password_verify($pass, $row['password'])) {
        // okay
    } else {
        // no such user/password
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Would it be a good idea if I made a class for things like that? i.e. a class with two methods. One of which for user info and the other for the admins?

Comment: @schmitsz if it would benefit you using classes then do so, you might need to reuse some methods then i think it would be good